# How to unit test a class having a dependency on OutboundDeliveryV2ServiceBatch?

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns, sap-cloud-sdk

*Using java SAP Cloud SDK*

I am trying to write unit tests for a custom class, let's call it, `OutboundDeliveryUpdater` which has a dependency on `com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.outbounddeliveryv2.batch.OutboundDeliveryV2ServiceBatch` (it is a class field). The requirement is to update multiple Outbound Delivery Items on the S4 system. The method in `OutboundDeliveryUpdater` which performs the update looks like this (omitting exception handling for brevity):

```
OutboundDeliveryV2ServiceBatchChangeSet changeSet = outboundDeliveryService.beginChangeSet();

itemsForUpdation.forEach(changeSet::updateOutbDeliveryItem);

changeSet.endChangeSet();

BatchResponse batchResponse = outboundDeliveryService.execute(destination);

boolean isUpdateSuccessful = batchResponse.get(0).isSuccess();
```

Now the problem is that while writing unit test for the above code, following things have to be mocked:

1. `outboundDeliveryService.beginChangeSet()` and `outboundDeliveryService.execute(destination)`
2. `destination`, which is an instance of HttpDestination
3. `changeSet.updateOutbDeliveryItem()`
4. `batchResponse.get()`

This makes the unit test very complicated. We have to mock a real dependency (`outboundDeliveryService`) and the objects that are returned by the methods which are executed on that dependency (`changeSet`, `batchResponse`). This seems to be a classic violation of [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and the code demonstrates the flaw of [digging into collaborators](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-digging-into-collaborators/) and this is the reason why it is becoming hard to write unit tests for this code.

Is there a better way of writing:

1. The unit tests for this code to prevent all this complexity?
2. If not then is there a better way of designing `OutboundDeliveryUpdater` so that the issue is solved? For e.g. `OutboundDeliveryUpdater` can have a dependency on a new class, let's say, `SomeService` which acts as a facade and hides the complexity of `OutboundDeliveryV2ServiceBatchChangeSet`. But this again will shift the complexity of testing from `OutboundDeliveryUpdater`'s unit test to `SomeService`'s test.

Comment: Can you make clearer where exactly (I mean in which line) you see the Law of Demeter violated?

Comment: 2nd line `itemsForUpdation.forEach(changeSet::updateOutbDeliveryItem)` and last line `boolean isUpdateSuccessful = batchResponse.get(0).isSuccess()`. Basically we are digging into `changeSet` and `batchResponse` by calling the respective methods on them. This leaves us with no choice but to mock the respective methods which are called on them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/)? It allows to use "Deep Mocking" as per [this example](https://idodevjobs.wordpress.com/2015/04/09/mockito-deep-stubs-example/).

An **alternative** to mock all the dependencies of this class for the purpose of an isolated unit test is to use [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/).

Following this approach, you would launch a tiny HTTP server during test execution which basically mocks the SAP S/4HANA system. Furthermore, you would tell WireMock which OData response it should send on which OData request.

Note that this approach does not provide you the notion of isolated unit-testing your custom class, it rather allows you to test the integration of **all** involved Java classes.

In the end, it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. We are using Mockito itself for mocking. But it doesn't solve the problem that I've mentioned in my question. The whole problem is that we are required to mock some objects, which are returned by dependencies which have already been mocked. This requires the test to know about the behavior of the objects which are returned by calling some methods on the dependency, which is in turn leading to complexity. If there is any change in the API of these objects, then the test will again have to be modified, just for the sake of this, with there being no change in business logic.

Comment: Regarding WireMock, we are already writing integration tests. Unit testing is what we are looking at right now. I guess there is a straightforward way unless the API is simplified or if we write a facade to simplify it.

Comment: I linked an example of "Deep Mocking" with Mockito in my answer. Possibly this helps to reduce your mocking effort.
Overall we have to note that the number of mocked instances (we counted approximately 7 as per your code sample) is a result of the fluent API of the Cloud SDK which, simply speaking, introduces different Java types for each needed return type.

Comment: Yes, this may reduce a few lines of boilerplate code. Thank you.